# How to search a particular character in a string in KornShell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

My KornShell (ksh) script receives command line arguments as input.
My task is to check if those arguments contains **abc** in it and print only those arguments which contain **abc** in it.
For Example:-

```
./tree.sh rabc try qwerty
```

Output should be ::

```
rabc
```

This is what I have tried:

```
var=$*
z=grep "abc" var
echo $z
```

Any insight regarding this?

Comment: It would help if you also show what you've tried so far. Others can then help you understand what went wrong. Simply providing a requirement and expecting others to give you the full solution is generally frowned upon on [so].

Comment: What went wrong with what you tried? How have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to be able to loop over the arguments. If we take a look at `man ksh`, we find the below:

> ```
> for vname [ in word ... ] ;do list ;done
> ```
>
> Each time a `for` command is executed, `vname` is set to the next `word` taken from the `in word` list. If `in word  ...` is  omitted, then  the `for` command executes the `do list` once for each positional parameter that is set starting from 1 (see Parameter Expansion below).  Execution ends when there are no more words in the list.

So to get the loop, we'll need something like this:

```
for arg
do
    <stuff>
done
```

At the point we're running `<stuff>`, `$arg` will be one of the parameters passed in. Note you need the `$` part at the front; ksh requires this to know to use the value stored in the variable, not just the variable name as-is.

Next, we need to work out whether `$arg` contains `abc`. We'll use `grep`, but remember `grep` looks through files you give it, or through whatever's passed in on it's standard input ("stdin"). The `grep "abc" var` you've given would have `grep` trying to look for `abc` in a file called `var`.

We need to get `$arg` into `grep`'s stdin. We'll use `echo`, which puts things onto standard output ("stdout"), and a "pipe", which joins one command's stdin to another's stdout:

```
echo "$arg" | grep abc
```

The above will put whatever's in `$arg` onto stdin, then `grep` will print it only if it contains `abc`.

Thus the complete script is as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for arg
do
    echo "$arg" | grep abc
done
```

This won't properly handle the case where arguments contain newlines; I'll leave that as a future problem for you to resolve yourself.

Comment: can i store the value returned by echo "$arg" | grep abc in a variable ?? Because when i do var=echo "$arg" | grep abc, Nothing is displayed in $var.. please help

Comment: @user1466466: You need to use "command substitution": `var=$(echo "$arg" | grep abc)`. Without that, ksh can't tell between you wanting to store the string "echo …" and you wanting to store the output of running that string as a command.